# Object doesn't support property or method 'dispatchEvent'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Can someone tell me why I get this error in Intenet Explorer 11?

```
function triggerHtmlEvent(element, eventName) {
  var event;
  if(document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = eventName;
    element.fireEvent('on' + event.eventType, event);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `element`?

Answer (score 0):

The current way to dispatch an event is with `new CustomEvent`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

```
// Create the event:
var event = new CustomEvent('build');
// Dispatch the event:
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You should also make sure that you have a valid item passed in as your `element` not everything can send events, such as `null`, `undefined`, and some other things.